# Easier Way? Creating A Fold in Blender

Tags: armature, bones

I work with a program called ArtiosCad that has limited 3-D capabilities. I'm able to use it for basic design work, but have recently been asked to create a graphic so that we can show off how boxes fold up for our customers.

A standard "flap" is easy enough to fold up with an armature bone on each flap, but when I try to recreate it with two folding flaps, everything seems to fight me.

I don't want to overlook the simple solution as I dive into an easier one, so I was curious is there a better or different way to capture the following effect?

[image]

In the end, I may have to end up using the graphic posted above, but I was hoping to do it in a cleaner way. Not afraid to dive in and learn the next steps, but want to make sure I'm not running down the "wrong" path.

Thank you!

SOLUTION:

Using the answer given I was able to create the following
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an armature, and create one bone by fold, like this (the central one being the parent of all the bones):

[image]

Give your bones names, parent the object to the armature with *With Empty Groups* option, select the vertices of a fold in *Edit* mode and in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, assign these vertices to the vertex group they are supposed to be part of (the vertex group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control these vertices).

You can also give some *Limit Rotation* constraints to each bone so that they only rotate on the right axis.

Comment: This was a huge help for me. Not sure what it sparked, but between parenting to the armature on the "main" part of the design, as well as making the two bones in the "arm" connected (as well as parenting the second bone to the first, this worked out just how I needed it to.

Comment: ok, great then  ;)  if you have a question don't hesitate